# How to know if Entity was using SQL Server or not?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio

I have followed through a tutorial using a "Code First" approach with Entity framework. It seems like Visual Studio was smart enough to create the database for me and setup the tables and everything based on my classes. I have a question about the database that was created.

I notice that the database was automatically set up and I could see it in my Server Explorer window in Visual Studio. In my `Web.config`, under the connection string, I see `Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;...`. There is also a `.mdf` file created in a folder called `App_Data`.

My question is:

- Was Entity framework using MS SQL Server or SQL Express for the database it has created?
- If it wasn't using MS SQL Server or SQL Express, what was the database that Entity used?
- I don't remember installing SQL Server or SQL Express. Does installing Visual Studio automatically install MS SQL Server or SQL Server Express?

*PS: I will appreciate if you can help me to clear up my doubts. Coming from a PHP background, I'm very new to .NET and its ecosystem.*

Comment: FYI, installing Visual Studio automatically install MS SQL Server compact/express edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection string indicate that you are using SQL Server Local DB.

With Microsoft SQL Server 2012, Microsoft has introduced a feature called LocalDB which is a new edition of SQL Express. LocalDB is created specifically for developers and it is much easier to install (no service) and manage than standard editions. Developers initiate a connection by using a special connection string. It supports AttachDbFileName property, which allows you to specify a database file location.

When connecting, the server is automatically created and started, enabling the application to use the database without complex configuration tasks. This edition uses the same sqlservr.exe as the regular SQL Express and other editions of SQL Server.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/evalcenter/dn434042.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh212961.aspx